# different consumer consuming same message from a queue, consumer code is a time taking process in this case and so might not be acknowledging in time

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, queue, ibm-mq

I have a consumer process which has to do heavy lifting, it is a process that takes more than 30 sec to complete. And we acknowledge the message when process is completed successfully. However, looks like queue is waiting for acknowledgement and as it does not receive the acknowledgement within time, it's putting the message back to queue and same message is consumed by other consumer instance. Are there any config that I can tweak?? I don't want to auto acknowledge the message as it's an important flow and autoscaling down of the cluster may cause message loss.

I am looking if there is any config that can help me with it or is my understanding incorrect? I don't want same message getting consumed by more than one consumer. We're using IBM MQ in this instance.

Comment: What return code do you receive when the message is rolled back?

Comment: You should clarify your question. IBM MQ doesn’t use acknowledgments.

Comment: Do you have any source confirming that IBM MQ doesn’t use acknowledgments.? @AttilaRepasi

Answer (score 2):

> However, looks like queue is waiting for acknowledgement and as it
> does not receive the acknowledgement within time, it's putting the
> message back to queue and same message is consumed by other consumer
> instance.

Neither the queue nor the queue manager by itself puts the message back to the queue.  There is one exception to that rule and that is if the client application crashes.  If the queue manager determines that the application has crashed then it will rollback the message to the queue.

Or are you saying that if the sending application does not receive an acknowledgement within a specified amount of time then it resends the same message?  If that is the case, then tell the sending application to double or triple the wait time.